# JSON only works with Debug mode but not work in apk file in android

Tags: android, json

My android application only works with debug mode but not works when i convert the app in to apk file.I found that the problem with json only.While i turned off the network(i.e internet) it was worked well but i turned on the network and try to open my application it leads to crash the application.

This is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class MapList extends Activity {
    GoogleMap Gmap;
    GPSTracker gps;
    JSONObject jobj;
    EditText searchEdit;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
    Marker blueMarker,redMarker;
    String Countryname;
    Context con=MapList.this;
 public static final String URl="http://www.dealsocl.com/mysql2json_SG.php";
     RelativeLayout listRelative,mapRelative;
        // public static final String URl="http://192.168.0.6/singapore_dealsocl/mysql2json_TM.php";
 public static final String Tag_val="data";
 public static final String Tag_dealid="dealid";
 public static final String Tag_title="title";
    public static final String Tag_price="price";
    public static final String Tag_worth="value";
    public static final String Tag_saving="saving";
    public static final String Tag_saving_percent="saving_percent";
    public static final String Tag_imageurl="imageurl";
    public static final String Tag_link="link";
    public static final String Tag_latitude="latitude";
    public static final String Tag_longitude="longitude";
    public static final String Tag_siteName="name";
    public static final String Tag_price_sign="price_sign";
    public static final String Tag_cat_seo="cat_seo_title";


      ArrayList<String>lat_arry=new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String>long_arry=new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String>deal_tite=new ArrayList<String>();

      ArrayList<Double> mydoublat=new ArrayList<Double>();
      ArrayList<Double> mydoublong=new ArrayList<Double>();

      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>details=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(details);
      HashMap<String, String>map;
      ListAdapter myAdapter;
      ListView DataList;
    ImageView nearby,search,home,account;
    String s;

    //String[] url={"http://www.dealsocl.com/mysql2json_SG.php","http://www.dealsocl.in/mysql2json_IN.php"};
    ArrayList<String>url=new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( new String[]{"http://www.dealsocl.in/mysql2json_IN.php","http://www.dealsocl.com/mysql2json_SG.php","http://www.dealsocl.com/mysql2json_AE.php"} ) );

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maplist);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


         gps = new GPSTracker(MapList.this);

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)       
                  con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                   NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                       NetworkInfo mobileInfo = 
                        connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

                       if (wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileInfo.isConnected()) {
                         // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "network connected", 1000).show();

                            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                 longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                                 Log.e("laaaaaaaaaatttttttiiiiiiii", ""+latitude);
                                    Log.e("longiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", ""+longitude);





                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                // can't get location
                                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                             //   gps.showSettingsAlert();
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
                                intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
                                sendBroadcast(intent);
                                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                 longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
                            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
                              Log.e("latii1", ""+latitude);
                                Log.e("longiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", ""+longitude);
                            List<Address> matches = null;
                            try {
                                  Log.e("latiiii2", ""+latitude);
                                    Log.e("longiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", ""+longitude);
                                matches = geoCoder.getFromLocation( latitude, longitude, 1);
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+matches, 1000).show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Address bestMatch = (matches.isEmpty() ? null : matches.get(0));
                            //String countryname=bestMatch.getCountryName().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your country name is:"+bestMatch.getCountryName(), 1000).show();


                             Countryname=bestMatch.getCountryName().toUpperCase().toString();
                            Log.e("address", ""+Countryname);    
                   //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->        



                            if(Countryname.equalsIgnoreCase("India")){
                                     s=url.get(0).toString();
                                Log.e("country check1",s);
                                MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask=new MyAsyncTask();

                                 myAsyncTask.execute(s);

                            }else if(Countryname.equalsIgnoreCase("SINGAPORE")){
                                 s=url.get(1).toString();
                                Log.i("country check1", s);
                                MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask=new MyAsyncTask();

                                 myAsyncTask.execute(s);

                            }else if(Countryname.equalsIgnoreCase("UNITED ARAB EMIRATES")){
                                 s=url.get(2).toString();
                                Log.e("country check1", s);
                                MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask=new MyAsyncTask();

                                 myAsyncTask.execute(s);

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Currently no deals in your location", 1000).show();

                            }
                      }else{
                         RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.realtivemap1);
                         RelativeLayout rl1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.listrlayout2);
                         //TextView alertText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAlert);



                         rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         rl1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                              public void run() {

                                  finish();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent); 
                                    overridePendingTransition(R.animator.left_to_right, R.animator.slide_out_bottom);
                              }


                          }, 10000);
                      }



                       DataList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                      searchEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchEd);

                      mapRelative=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.realtivemap1);
                      listRelative=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.listrlayout2);







                searchEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                                //clear the initial data set

                          String searchString=searchEdit.getText().toString();
                          int textLength=searchString.length();

                                 //clear the initial data set
                          searchResults.clear();

                          for(int i=0;i<details.size();i++)
                          {
                         String titleString=details.get(i).get(Tag_title).toString();


                         if(textLength<=titleString.length()){

                         //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                           if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(titleString.substring(0,textLength)))
                               /*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),playerName,1).show();*/
                           searchResults.add(details.get(i));
                         }
                          }

                          myAdapter=new LazyAdapter1(MapList.this, searchResults);
                          DataList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                          ((BaseAdapter) myAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

           /*   MapListActivity.this.myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);    */

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                            int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                DataList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        String title=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.getText_s_)).getText().toString();
                        String price=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Price_s_)).getText().toString();
                        String savings=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Saving_s_)).getText().toString();
                        String worth=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Worth_s_)).getText().toString();
                        String discount=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Discount_s_)).getText().toString();
                        String sitename=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Site_n_)).getText().toString();
                        String imageText=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageTextURl_s_)).getText().toString();
                        String lat=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lat_s)).getText().toString();
                        String lng=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lng_s)).getText().toString();
                        Log.i(Tag_title, title);
                        Log.i(Tag_price, price);
                        Log.i(Tag_saving, savings);
                        Log.i(Tag_worth, worth);
                        Log.i(Tag_saving_percent, discount);
                        Log.i(Tag_siteName, sitename);
                        Log.i(Tag_imageurl, imageText);
                        /*Log.i(Tag_latitude,""+lat);
                        Log.i(Tag_longitude,""+ lng);*/
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_title, title);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_price, price);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_saving, savings);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_worth, worth);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_saving_percent, discount);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_siteName, sitename);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_imageurl, imageText);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_latitude, lat);
                        in.putExtra(Tag_longitude, lng);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }



                });



    }
    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> > {
         ProgressDialog dialog;



                 @Override
             protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {

           /*  JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(params[0]);*/
                     JsonParser parser=new JsonParser();

                    try {

                        jobj=parser.getJsonUrl(s);



                        Log.e("jobj", ""+jobj);
                        JSONArray array=jobj.getJSONArray(Tag_val);
                        /*Log.e("array", ""+array);*/
                        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                        /*  Log.e("array", ""+array);*/
                            JSONObject c=array.getJSONObject(i);
                            /*Log.e("object", ""+c);*/
                            /*String id=c.getString(Tag_dealid);*/
                            String title=c.getString(Tag_title);
                            String price=c.getString(Tag_price);
                            String value=c.getString(Tag_worth);
                            String saving=c.getString(Tag_saving);
                            String sav_perc=c.getString(Tag_saving_percent);
                            /*String link=c.getString(Tag_link);*/
                            String lat=c.getString(Tag_latitude);
                            String longi=c.getString(Tag_longitude);
                            String image=c.getString(Tag_imageurl);
                            String siteName=c.getString(Tag_siteName);
                            String price_sign=c.getString(Tag_price_sign);
                            String cat_seo_title=c.getString(Tag_cat_seo);

                            Log.i("lat", lat);
                            Log.i("longi",longi);
                            lat_arry.add(lat);
                            long_arry.add(longi);
                             deal_tite.add(title);





                           Log.e("lat_arry",lat_arry.get(i));
                           Log.e("long_arry",long_arry.get(i));

                        map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                            //map.put(Tag_dealid, id);
                            map.put(Tag_title, title);
                            map.put(Tag_worth, value);
                            map.put(Tag_saving, saving);
                            map.put(Tag_saving_percent, sav_perc);
                            map.put(Tag_price,price);
                            map.put(Tag_siteName,siteName);
                            map.put(Tag_price_sign,price_sign);



                        //  map.put(Tag_link, link);
                            map.put(Tag_latitude, lat);
                            map.put(Tag_longitude, longi);
                            map.put(Tag_imageurl, image);
                            map.put(Tag_cat_seo, cat_seo_title);
                            /*Double long1 = longitude;
                            Double lat1 = latitude;
                            String[] doublong= long_arry.toArray(new String[long_arry.size()]);
                            doublong=long_arry.toArray(doublong);
                            double[] doub_long = new double[doublong.length];
                              doub_long[i] = Double.parseDouble(doublong[i]);
                                mydoublong.add(doub_long[i]);

                               String[] doublat= lat_arry.toArray(new String[lat_arry.size()]);
                                doublong=lat_arry.toArray(doublong);
                                double[] doub_lat = new double[doublat.length];
                                  doub_lat[i] = Double.parseDouble(doublat[i]);
                                    mydoublat.add(doub_lat[i]);

                            Double d=DistanceBetweenPlaces(longitude,latitude, mydoublong.get(i), mydoublat.get(i));
                            String distance=new Double(d).toString();
                            Log.w("Distance", ""+distance);
                            map.put("dist", distance);*/
                            details.add(map);

                        }
                 return details;
         }catch(JSONException e)        {
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
         }
             return null;
             }

             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            myAdapter=new LazyAdapter1(MapList.this, details);

                DataList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                dialog.dismiss();
}



                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MapList.this);
                    dialog.setMessage("Your deals are loading....");
                   /* dialog.setIndeterminate(false);*/
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.show();
                }


     }



        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent); 
            overridePendingTransition(R.animator.left_to_right, R.animator.slide_out_bottom);
        }


}
```

This is my json parser code:

```
public class JsonParser {

    JSONObject jobj;
    String json="";
    InputStream is=null;

    public JSONObject getJsonUrl(String url){

        DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            is=entity.getContent();


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;

            try {
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json=sb.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            jobj=new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jobj;

    }
}
```

and Important thing is if i convert into apk file and run the apk file into the devices which was i used to debug the application that devices works fine (i.e that apk able to run on the deveice) but other devices it will not work(i.e it will not open or not run on the device)

can anyone please solve this issue?

Comment: Give us the crash (exception trace) from LogCat

Comment: check if u device have internet and post the snip of logcat

Comment: And, please, only include the relevant pieces of your code, not your entire java file.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in Proguard File

```
-keep class org.json.** { *;}
```

Proguard obfuscated the JSON Object class. In debug builds, Proguard is generally disabled so the problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but same problem here after several years.
I solved by "lowering" the linking option to "sdk assemblies only" in the release configuration.

[image]

The linking option is tricky. "sdk and user assemblies" does not do what it may seem (adding user assemblies). However, it searches for unused code also in user assemblies, but the linker may misjudge code outside the sdk and remove necessary code.